# Is it possible to view passwords of firebase password-based accounts?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a website that uses firebase for authentication. I want to know if it is possible to view the passwords of the password-based accounts created on my website.

Is it possible? With Javascript or the firebase console.

I looked this question up, and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you are able to defeat the cryptographic hashing and salting algorithms used to represent the passwords.

Comment: Not unless they have unknown advanced solutions for reverse engineering the algorithms.